# Today Extension - iOS

Tags: ios, today-extension

I know to set the height of our today extension in notification centre using preferredcontentsize property.But i need a way to set the height of our today widget using auto layout.Please help me.Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: follow this link, http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

Comment: thanks for suggesting the link.i found nice explanation there.